# Check if a value is present in a range or not with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to check if a value is present in a range or not. If it's not there then I want it to jump to `WriteProcess` else I want it to give a message box saying it's present and exit the sub.

This is code,

```
    'Write the Selected Value in the Range - Next Available row in the Column of Source
    For i = TableStartingRow + 1 To AddNewEntrow        
        If Range(EntryColLett & i).Value = wb21Tool.Sheets("Home").ComboBox1.Value Then
            MsgBox "The data exists in the Table"
            GoTo StopSub       
        Else
            GoTo WriteProcess
        End If
    Next

WriteProcess:
    wbTool.Sheets("Home").Range(EntryColLett & AddNewEntrow).Value = wb21Tool.Sheets("Home").ComboBox1.Value

StopSub:   
    'Turn on the ScreenUpdate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Please share your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a question here?  The code snippet looks like it would work just fine.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Seems better to use the range `Find` method or `Application.Match` function but I don't see what's wrong with this code. Please elaborate.

Comment: @tigeravatar Yes Sir. It works fine. But its not doing what I want it do. When I run the code on debugging mode, I found out that it runs the else loop before it runs all the values in the increment i. I want the code to check through all the values in increment i and only if its not matching in all of those, it has to go to WriteProcess.

Comment: @DavidZemens Say i has values of 1,2,3. It runs for the loop as i =1 and when it doesn't match it goes into the Write Process. I want it to run until 3 and when it doesn't match it needs to go to the write process and if there is a match found before that. It has to give the message box and go to stopsub.

Comment: Ah, yes, makes perfect sense I will write an answer.

Comment: @DavidZemens Perfect :)

Comment: If you want to iterate through all `i` values before going to the `StopSub`, why not just take out the `Else` part, and put `GoTo StopSub`  after the `Next`? (Although you really shouldn't be using `GoTo`, but that's a different subject...)  Right now, for *each* `i` value, if the `...Value`s don't equal, it's going to go to the `StopSub` line...

Comment: @BruceWayne Simple solution. Works for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternate solution if you need to check every row before performing the "WriteProcess":

```
    Dim bExists As Boolean

    bExists = False
    'Write the Selected Value in the Range - Next Available row in the Column of Source
    For i = TableStartingRow + 1 To AddNewEntrow
        If Range(EntryColLett & i).Value = wb21Tool.Sheets("Home").ComboBox1.Value Then
            bExists = True
            MsgBox "The data exists in the Table"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not bExists Then wbTool.Sheets("Home").Range(EntryColLett & AddNewEntrow).Value = wb21Tool.Sheets("Home").ComboBox1.Value

    'Turn on the ScreenUpdate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that if the loop expires (exhausts all of the iterations) there is no control to prevent it from entering the WriteProcess.

This is one problem with using `GoTo` statements. Preferably keep these to a minimum. For example, although this doesn't check *every* row, just an example of how you might avoid the extra `GoTo`.

```
    'Write the Selected Value in the Range - Next Available row in the Column of Source
    For i = TableStartingRow + 1 To AddNewEntrow        
        If Range(EntryColLett & i).Value = wb21Tool.Sheets("Home").ComboBox1.Value Then
            MsgBox "The data exists in the Table"
            GoTo StopSub       
        Else
            wbTool.Sheets("Home").Range(EntryColLett & AddNewEntrow).Value = wb21Tool.Sheets("Home").ComboBox1.Value
        End If
    Next

StopSub:   
    'Turn on the ScreenUpdate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

However, a brute-force iteration over the table data seems unnecessary and if you need to check *all* rows int he table it's probably better to just use the `Find` method.

Assuming `EntryColLet` is a string representing the column letter:

```
    Dim tblRange as Range
    Dim foundRow as Range
    Set tblRange = Range(EntryColLet & (TableStartingRow+1) & ":" & EntryColLet & AddNewEntRow)
    Set foundRow = tblRange.Find(wb21Tool.Sheets("Home").ComboBox1.Value)
    If foundRow Is Nothing Then
        'The value doesn't exist in the table, so do something
        '
    Else
        'The value exists already
        MsgBox "The data exists in the Table"
        GoTo StopSub
    End If

    'More code, if you have any...

StopSub:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

And regarding the remaining `GoTo` -- if there's no more code that executes after the condition `If foundRow Is Nothing` then you can remove the entire `Else` clause *and* the `GoTo` label:

```
    Dim tblRange as Range
    Dim foundRow as Range
    Set tblRange = Range(EntryColLet & (TableStartingRow+1) & ":" & EntryColLet & AddNewEntRow)
    Set foundRow = tblRange.Find(wb21Tool.Sheets("Home").ComboBox1.Value)
    If foundRow Is Nothing Then
        'The value doesn't exist in the table, so do something
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I understood, where I am going wrong sir. Thanks. But my requirement was still not matched. Thanks.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with your suggestion that using a `Range.Find` method is much better than iterating over each cell